# What commands are valid in "console pane" of Mac's "Instruments" app? (E.g., in Instrument)

Tags: iphone, console, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm running the Mac OS "Instruments" app, using the "Leaks Instrument" to monitor an
iPhone app.  The major pane is titled "Leaked Blocks", but if you click on that you
get a choice of three: "Leaked Blocks", "Call Tree", and "Console".  Click on "Console".

You now have a blank pane ... click in it and hit .
In my case, I get:

foo (4259) >

which is my app name and, presumably, the PID it's running as.

I can enter commands/text (e.g., ls, help, exit) ... they get echoed after awhile but
nothing else happens.

I.e., it *looks* like a command prompt, but I can't figure out what kinds of commands
I can give it here!  Doesn't seem to accept gdb commands, nor "help".  Can't find a 
mention of this feature in Apple's documents.

Note that if I select a different instrument, e.g. "Allocations", it also has the
same console pane ... with the same "no effect" when I enter text.

I'm hoping that whatever commands it has are (a) interesting, and (b) useful to me
in debugging a memory leak.

thanks,
Stan
sieler@me.com

Comment: Did you ever find out the valid commands? I am having the same question

Comment: Momo... sorry, never found out anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a console window that lets you see messages printed to the console (NSLog and alike), just like Xcode's one? In Xcode too you can write in that console, to no extent...

indeed the [Instruments User Guide states:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/SpecifyingtheProcesstoTrace/SpecifyingtheProcesstoTrace.html)

> Options
>
> Use this menu to specify other runtime options. For example, you can direct the application’s output to the Instruments console or the system console, or discard the output. You can also specify whether the application is launched in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

did not try it, though...

Comment: I thought that too (that I could see messages) ... but I can't.  I added a "printf" and I can see its output in xcode's debugger window, but not in the Instrument's console panel ... and even if that was supposed to show up there, it wouldn't explain the "prompt" with the app name and PID.

Comment: Also, I checked that page ... the "Options" does not seem to appear for my iOS app.  That "choose target to launch" picture on the web page differs fairly significantly from what the Mac OS X 10.6.7 Instruments "app" displays :(

Comment: Being new to stackoverflow, I'm guessing that clicking the "helpful" adds to your rating, so I'm doing that to say "thanks", even though it didn't answer the question about commands I can enter.

Comment: hey, thanks! you are right about the fact that "options" is not appearing in Instruments iOS guide... my bad... but it also occurs to me that the Instruments app is just one, both for iOS and MacOS, so maybe the console is there just for MacOS... just speculating...